# Referer missing in HTTP header of Selenium request

Tags: python, selenium, testing, http-headers, http-referer

I'm writing some tests with Selenium and noticed, that `Referer` is missing from the headers. I wrote the following minimal example to test this with https://httpbin.org/headers:

```python
import selenium.webdriver

options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled', False)

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
wait = selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('http://www.python.org')
assert 'Python' in driver.title

url = 'https://httpbin.org/headers'
driver.execute_script('window.location.href = "{}";'.format(url))
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == url)
print(driver.page_source)

driver.close()
```

Which prints:

```html
<html><head><link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://content-accessible/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines"></head><body><pre>{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
  }
}
</pre></body></html>
```

So there is no `Referer`. However, if I browse to any page and manually execute

```
window.location.href = "https://httpbin.org/headers"
```

in the Firefox console, `Referer` *does* appear as expected.

---

As pointed out in the comments below, when using

```
driver.get("javascript: window.location.href = '{}'".format(url))
```

instead of

```
driver.execute_script("window.location.href = '{}';".format(url))
```

the request does include `Referer`. Also, when using Chrome instead of Firefox, both methods include `Referer`.

So the main question still stands: Why is `Referer` missing in the request when sent with Firefox as described above?

Comment: The issue here is a bug in the Firefox driver / Marionette. To get the `Referer`, run `driver.get("javascript: window.location.href = 'https://httpbin.org/headers' ")`.

Comment: it's a bug since the default policy in place should not block it and mostly because it is present when the location is changed directly via the console or when the driver is switched to Chrome.

Comment: nope, if it was a policy defined by the gecko driver, then you wouldn't get the `Referer` when the location is changed manually in the console. My guess is that the JavaScript sandbox is somehow interfering.

Answer (score 7):

## `Referer` as per the MDN documentation

> The `Referer` request header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed. The `Referer` header allows servers to identify where people are visiting them from and may use that data for analytics, logging, or optimized caching, for example.
>
> > Important: Although this header has many innocent uses it can have undesirable consequences for user security and privacy.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

---

However:

> A Referer header is not sent by browsers if:
>
> - The referring resource is a local "file" or "data" URI.
> - An unsecured HTTP request is used and the referring page was received with a secure protocol (HTTPS).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

---

## Privacy and security concerns

There are some privacy and security risks associated with the `Referer` HTTP header:

> The `Referer` header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed, which can be further used for analytics, logging, or optimized caching.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Referer_header:_privacy_and_security_concerns#The_referrer_problem

---

## Addressing the security concerns

From the `Referer` header perspective majority of security risks can be mitigated following the steps:

> - [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy): Using the `Referrer-Policy` header on your server to control what information is sent through the Referer header. Again, a directive of no-referrer would omit the Referer header entirely.
> - The `referrerpolicy` attribute on HTML elements that are in danger of leaking such information (such as `<img>` and `<a>`). This can for example be set to `no-referrer` to stop the `Referer` header being sent altogether.
> - The `rel` attribute set to `noreferrer` on HTML elements that are in danger of leaking such information (such as `<img>` and `<a>`).
> - The [Exit Page Redirect](https://geekthis.net/post/hide-http-referer-headers/#exit-page-redirect) technique: This is the only method that should work at the moment without flaw is to have an exit page that you don’t mind having inside of the `referer` header. Many websites implement this method, including Google and Facebook. Instead of having the referrer data show private information, it only shows the website that the user came from, if implemented correctly. Instead of the referrer data appearing as `http://example.com/user/foobar` the new referrer data will appear as `http://example.com/exit?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`. The way the method works is by having all external links on your website go to a intermediary page that then redirects to the final page. Below we have a link to the website `example.com` and we URL encode the full URL and add it to the `url` parameter of our exit page.

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Referer_header:_privacy_and_security_concerns#How_can_we_fix_this
- https://geekthis.net/post/hide-http-referer-headers/#exit-page-redirect

---

## This usecase

I have executed your code through both through GeckoDriver/Firefox and ChromeDriver/Chrome combination:

#### Code Block:

```
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
assert 'Python' in driver.title

url = 'https://httpbin.org/headers'
driver.execute_script('window.location.href = "{}";'.format(url))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

#### Observation:

- Using GeckoDriver/Firefox `Referer:  "https://www.python.org/"` header was **missing** as follows:

  ```
      {
        "headers": {
          "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
          "Host": "httpbin.org", 
          "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
        }
      }
  ```
- Using ChromeDriver/Chrome `Referer:  "https://www.python.org/"` header was **present** as follows:

  ```
      {
        "headers": {
          "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
          "Host": "httpbin.org", 
          "Referer": "https://www.python.org/", 
          "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36"
        }
      }
  ```

#### Conclusion:

It seems to be an issue with GeckoDriver/Firefox in handling the `Referer` header.

---

## Outro

[Referrer Policy](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security.html#referrer-policy)

Comment: As per your conclusion, the only way to `Referer` will be via `execute_script`?

Comment: The BrowserMob proxy isn't actively maintained and hasn't had a release in 3 years. Might I suggest the BrowserUp Proxy http://browserup.com/blog/announcement-an-actively-maintained-fork-of-the-browsermob-proxy/

It is a drop in replacement for the BrowserMob Proxy, but with added HTTP/2, Brotli support, Support up to Java 11 (BrowserMob only goes to 8), Modern Dependencies and active maintainers.

Comment: The current implementation of `execute_script` simply fails to add the `Referer` header. It has nothing to do with retrieving the headers from the conversion you are mentioning.

Comment: @DebanjanB So now you changed your conclusion to "It seems to be an issue with GeckoDriver/Firefox in handling the Referer header". I mean, yes, but what *is* the issue? How can I fix it? Is it desired behavior or a bug?